# Using dependency injection with an ApiController when it also needs an empty constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, unity-container

I have an ApiController in an Area of my MVC website, I'm injecting dependencies into it via Unity and my controllers extend the System.Web.Http.ApiController.

I'm using Unity from Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll, v3.0.0.0.

I can route to the controller with the following in ApiAreaRegistration

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Api_default",
    "Api/users/{action}/{id}"
);
```

But I get the following error :

> Type 'Project.Areas.Api.Controllers.UsersController' does not have a default constructor

However if I add a default constructor my dependencies don't get resolved.

I'm beginning to feel like I'm missing something structural?

Comment: `MapRoute` isn't related to your Unity problem. Is your controller extending `System.Web.Http.ApiController`? Are you using the `Unity.WebApi` package?

Comment: @Jasen, Thanks I've added the details to my original question.

Comment: You do realize that there are separate dependency resolver registrations for WebApi, compared to MVC, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new UnityDependencyResolver(YOUR_UNITY_CONTAINER);
```

and from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec18 you can find that you should search for 'Unity bootstrapper for ASP.NET WebApi' and you get the UnityDependencyResolver from the namespace: 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.WebApi'.

Easiest way is just to install the WebApi Bootstrapper and look in the App_Start folder.

Answer (score 3):

You don't show your controller registration and the error message suggests you have not registered the controller dependencies.

I use the [Unity.WebAPI](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.WebAPI/) NuGet package to take care of the controller build-up and container lifetime management. If your project also uses MVC controllers the [Unity.Mvc3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc3/) will handle those controllers. These packages get Unity wired-up for my controllers with very little code.

My Unity bootstrap looks like this

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    var container = BuildUnityContainer();

    // MVC controllers
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new Unity.Mvc3.UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    // WebAPI controllers
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(container);
}

private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // register all your components with the container here
    // you don't need to register controllers
    container.RegisterType<IUsersService, UsersService>();
    ...
    return container;
}
```

And I don't worry about my controller creation -- It just works.

```
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    private IUsersService service;

    public UsersController(IUsersService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    ...
}
```